# How to check if a list item within a nested list exists in a set?

Tags: python, set, nested-lists

I have a nested list of every sentence from a corpus. The set is all the words that occur more than once. How would I check if each word within the list is in the set containing only words that occur once?
I then need to replace all words that occur more than once with the str UNK.

I tried:

```
for sent in tokenized_sents:
    for word in sent:
        if word in set:
           word = '<UNK>'
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about how your list is built ? Can you give an example maybe ? Also, how is your set built ? You can use `collections.Counter` to build a "histogram" set which counts every occurences of elements in a list, which could make it more efficient.

Comment: So I had a corpus of part of a book. I then tokenized all the sentences so now I have a list containing individual lists of each sentence. I can give you the first few lines.

Comment: [['sir', 'walter', 'elliot', ',', 'of', 'kellynch', 'hall', ',', 'in', 'somersetshire', ',', 'was', 'a', 'man', 'who', ',', 'for', 'his', 'own', 'amusement', ',', 'never', 'took', 'up', 'any', 'book', 'but', 'the', 'baronetage', ';', 'there', 'he', 'found', 'occupation', 'for', 'an', 'idle', 'hour', ',', 'and', 'consolation', 'in', 'a', 'distressed', 'one', ';', 'there', 'his', 'faculties', 'were', 'roused', 'into', 'admiration', 'and', 'respect', ',', 'by', 'contemplating', 'the', 'limited', 'remnant', 'of', 'the', 'earliest', 'patents', ';', 'there', 'any', 'unwelcome', 'sensations', ']....]

Comment: So that's your list, and why is it nested ? does each element correspond to a sentence ? For instance, a simpler example with the sentence "Hello, my name is Walter. I like cats." would be `[['Hello', ',', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Walter'], ['I', 'like', 'cats']]`, is that right ?

Comment: each list corresponds to a sentence in the text. so in your example, ['Hello', ',', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Walter'] and ['I', 'like', 'cats'] are sentences within the corpus (ie; the list they're within)

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking because you described "the set" using exactly contradictory terms.  Can you either (a) give an example *in Python* of the input data and what you want the output data to be or (b) describe *in English* what you're trying to do with this book (like "replace all duplicate words within each sentence")?  Or better yet, both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary which keeps tracks of the number of occurrences of each word in your corpus with `collections.Counter`

```
from collections import Counter

corpus = [['Hello', ',', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Walter'], ['I', 'like', 'my', 'cats']]

corpus_unnested = []
for sentence in corpus:
    corpus_unnested += sentence
my_dict = Counter(corpus_unnested)

for i, sentence in enumerate(corpus):
    for j, word in enumerate(sentence):
        if my_dict[word] > 1:
            corpus[i][j] = '<UNK>'
```

```
>>> print(corpus)
[['Hello', ',', '<UNK>', 'name', 'is', 'Walter'], ['I', 'like', '<UNK>', 'cats']]
```